# Attach Auth Token to Requests Angular Fire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using angular fire to fetch and subscribe to collections/documents within my firebase database.

i am getting the data like so

```
this.db.collection('myCollection').valueChanges().subscribe( res => {
    // my logic entered here.
})
```

I need to attach an auth token to the requests that get sent to firebase.

I tried to create an interceptor where I could attach the auth token to the outgoing requests.

For some reason, AngularFire2 was not utilizing the interceptor.

Comment: Firestore uses its own connection (not the browser fetch API) to make queries. You can't intercept it.  You should use the REST API instead to make direct requests in a way that you can control. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

Comment: That's what I figured. Thank you for confirming!

Comment: How would you go about securing the db when using AngularFire?